# generating random number with lower bound excluded

Tags: java, random

I would like to generate a random number between x and y with the conditions (x, y] so x is excluded but y is included.

I am using Java.

I know that for the upper bound to be excluded it is `Math.random` * y but what do you do for lower bound? I am not sure how you would do it this way because the Math.random function returns the opposite [0, 1) so I am not sure how you would inverse that.

I also took a link at this source for answers but I didn't get any luck.
[https://careerkarma.com/blog/java-math-random/#:~:text=The%20Math.,is%20always%20less%20than%201](https://careerkarma.com/blog/java-math-random/#:%7E:text=The%20Math.,is%20always%20less%20than%201).

Please let me know

Comment: Why not generate a number with the upper bound excluded, and then subtract it to give a number with the lower bound excluded?

Comment: @khelwood that wouldnt work if you are looking for something like (0.0, y]

Comment: Why not? `y*(1-Math.random())`

Comment: Are you trying to generate a discrete or continuous distribution?  Uniformly distributed, or non-uniform?  If non-uniform, what specific distribution do you want?

Answer (score 1):

To get (0, 1], you can just take `1.0 - Math.random()`

```java
double randomDouble = 1.0 - Math.random();
```

From that you can just do the normal things to get between a random. For example, if you want any double that is (6, 10], you can just do this:

```java
double randomDouble = (1.0 - Math.random()) * (10.0 - 6.0) + 6.0;
```

Or just the generic

```java
double randomDouble = (1.0 - Math.random()) * (max - min) + min;
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Rule:**  If `a`  is in `[x, y[` then `a+1` is in  `]x,y]`

---

So the known formula is `double r = Math.random() * (upp - low) + low;`

So, using the `+1`, it becomes

```
Random rand = new Random()
int low = 10, upp = 20;

// for a double
double r = 1 + rand.nextDouble() * (upp - low) + low;

// for an int
int r = 1 + rand.nextInt(upp - low) + low;
```

Comment: You're assuming an `int` result is desired.